# The Rainbow Dream

Tags: creative-writing

May I draw pictures from magazines (photos of models, and people with their stories) for a book I would like to publish? Also, may I draw pictures from clip art for my book?

Answer (score 3):

It is good that you ask, because

#### no

you must not use published photographs as reference images for works that you plan to publish, no matter if you make money from your artwork or not.

If the reference image is copyrighted (which magazine photographs usually are), you must get permission to publish a derivative work both by the original copyright holder (e.g. the photographer or publisher) as well as possible people in the image (this is called a model release).